# Trouble with .htaccess rewriting .png/.php

Tags: htaccess, php, mod-rewrite, png

I'm currently creating a "dynamic signature" for a forum or email signature.

The php code writes perfectly fine onto an image with the .php page.

When trying to access the .png file with the userid, it doesn't show. 
I have a feeling it is the .htaccess file.

**How its supposed to look:** 
`https://v.example.com/sig.php?user_id=1`
[image]

**How it looks:** 
`https://v.example.com/sig.png?user_id=1`
[image]

what is in the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule sig.png sig.php
```

***UPDATE:***
I figured out i didn't have mod rewrite on in my AWS EC2 Instance. I just enabled it, and it still isn't working. :/

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

***UPDATE #2:*** Fixed. Was using bitnami wordpress and apache2, confusing apache setup had to give permission for apache2 to override.

Comment: Does the `sig.png` file exist?

Comment: Yes. both files exist.

Comment: `When trying to access the .png file with the userid, it doesn't show` <- What does that mean, why would you being accessing a `.png` file with a user ID as a parameter? Does the image show without the parameter? You'll need to clarify this a bit for users to be able to understand what your PHP code does and what you're trying to accomplish with this rewrite. Also note that Apache or your instance needs to be restarted when you enable modules.

Comment: @dan I created a php script that pulls database information and prints it onto the png image. Thats why it is pulling a user ID. I need it to be able to be a .png url so I can use this as a signature in emails or forums.

Comment: It's still a little unclear as to what you mean by `prints it onto the png image`, but perhaps the rewrite isn't including the query string - try [this](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA). This Stack Overflow question might also help: [.htaccess RewriteRule to preserve GET URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071155/htaccess-rewriterule-to-preserve-get-url-parameters). If that isn't helpful, please clarify what the URLs for the missing image are in the working PHP code example, and in the second example (from the page's the source code).

Comment: Your problem would seem to be that mod_rewrite and/or `.htaccess` is still not enabled. (The mod_rewrite directives themselves are "OK".) Since you have a physical file called `sig.png`, the behaviour you are seeing is consistent with this. You are simply requesting and being served `sig.png` as if your `.htaccess` file didn't exist.